# Count indices to array to produce heatmap

Tags: python, numpy

I'd like to accumulate indices that point to a `m-by-n` array to another array of that very shape to produce a heatmap. For example, these indices:

```
[
    [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]
    [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2]
]
```

would produce the following array:

```
[
    [2, 0, 0]
    [1, 1, 0]
    [1, 0, 1]
]
```

I've managed to succesfully implement an algorithm, but I started wondering, whether there is already a built-in `NumPy` solution for this kind of problem.

Here's my code:

```
a = np.array([[0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2]])

def _gather_indices(indices: np.ndarray, shape: tuple):
    heat = np.zeros(shape)
    for i in range(indices.shape[-1]):
        heat[tuple(indices[:, i])] += 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two methods could be suggested.

With `np.add.at` -

```
heat = np.zeros(shape,dtype=int)
np.add.at(heat,(a[0],a[1]),1)
```

Or with `tuple()` based one for a more *aesthetic* one -

```
np.add.at(heat,tuple(a),1)
```

With `bincount` -

```
idx = np.ravel_multi_index(a,shape)
np.bincount(idx,minlength=np.prod(shape)).reshape(shape)
```

Additionally, we could compute `shape` using the max-limits of the indices in `a` -

```
shape = a.max(axis=1)+1
```

Sample run -

```
In [147]: a
Out[147]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2]])

In [148]: shape = (3,3)

In [149]: heat = np.zeros(shape,dtype=int)
     ...: np.add.at(heat,(a[0],a[1]),1)

In [151]: heat
Out[151]: 
array([[2, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 1]])

In [173]: idx = np.ravel_multi_index(a,shape)

In [174]: np.bincount(idx,minlength=np.prod(shape)).reshape(shape)
Out[174]: 
array([[2, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 1]])
```

Comment: Nice, thanks a lot! Is this expandable to more dimensions? Seems like `(a[0], a[1])` could just be `tuple(a)` for that to happen.

Comment: You should add `minlength` to the `bincount` call, or the reshape will fail if the bottom right corner is not referenced.